# Index out of bounds error

Tags: java, loops, indexoutofboundsexception

I am having trouble with my code. I can tell why I am getting an index out of bound error. This code is suppose to combine 2 byte arrays into one. According to the "list[position] = byteAdd[t];" but I cannot figure out what's wrong. These arrays are initialized at 200 byte size.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("Enter a web Address");
String net = input.nextLine();
String nets [] = net.split("\\.");
byte[] length = new byte [200];
byte[] byteAdd= new byte[200];
int bytelength = byteAdd.length*2;
byte[] list = new byte [200]; 

for (int i = 0 ; i<nets.length; i++ )
{
    length[i]= (byte)(double) ( nets[i].length());  
    System.out.println(length[i]);
}

for (int i = 0 ; i<nets.length; i++ )
{
    byteAdd = nets[i].getBytes();
}

int position= 0 , max= 0;  

for (int i = 0 ; i<bytelength; i++)
{
    list[position]=length[i];
    position++;
    for (int t = 0 ; t<length[i]; t++)
    {
        list[position] = byteAdd[t];
        System.out.println(t+"   "+length[i]);
        System.out.println("Array lenght" + list.length);
        //System.out.println(t+"inner" + position);
        position++;
    }
    //System.out.println(i+"outter");
}
```

is this the stacktrace ?

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
>     at test.test.main(test.java:51)

The error is  on this line `list[position] = byteAdd[t];`

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?  What is the value of `bytelength`?

Comment: The stack trace (the most valuable piece of information you have here, which you forgot to show us) shows the index you are attempting to access and identifies the line the error is occurring on. What did you find out when you read it and examined the code?

Comment: On which line are you getting the exception?

Comment: @brianChiem So is the error when accessing `list` or when accessing `byteAdd`? When you print the values of `position` and `t`, which one of them is "3" at that point? "3" is an invalid index into one of those two arrays. Find out which, find out why, and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `list = new byte [200];` declares list of size `200`

`bytelength` is size `200*2` = 400

So when you say

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<bytelength; i++)
```

this means

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<400; i++) //whereas all array is limited to size 200 and that's throwing exception!
```

so, in your increment pointer, `position++`, this goes upto value 399 whereas, the array size is limited to `200`

so `list[position]` goes upto `list[201-400] // should be truncated at 200`

Answer (score 0):

position++ at two different places in the same loop will at some point cause the value of itself to be higher than the array length. Hence when trying to use it as an index to the loop, might throw An INDEXOUTOFBOUNDS exception when you're using that position value to index an out of range array index. Hence you might want to do:
Either check for the position's value(if it is lesser than the array length) before using it or alter your logic. We could help if you could be clearer with what you're trying to do.

Comment: I mean that statement is the cause for that error. Because he's incrementing the value of position at two different places, it will exceed the array length. better of to check if position<array.length before using it to index the array.

Comment: 1. While that may ultimately be the case, we do not know that because we do not know the length of `list` and we do not know the source of the exception (perhaps it is `length[i]`, or `byteAdd[t]`). 2. The correct solution would usually be to fix the logic so that the index never exceeds the length, rather than blindly doing a bounds check.

Comment: I've modified my answer. I should have framed my answer better. But then I just wanted to point out what the cause of the error was. which was a logic error caused by the use of pointer++

Comment: is there any you can suggestion that i can accomplish the same task with out the use of position?

Comment: for that, I would need to know: what you're trying to achieve here? and the values of all arrays you're using.

Comment: in one array, it contains the amount of values that is shows the for loop how many index it needs to print out before going to the first array. So in array a [ 3 , 2, 1 ] array b [ 1,2,3,4,5,6]
the final array would be [3,1,2,3,2,4,5,1,6]

Comment: I think it would be best if you can post the complete code here.